# RangeError rendering tree with Grafana plugin for Apache echarts from volkovlabs.io

Tags: javascript, json, grafana, echarts

We're trying to render a tree in this Grafana (v10.3.1 (00a22ff8b2)) plugin for apache echarts: [link](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/volkovlabs-echarts-panel/) (version 5.1.0) and we could use some help fixing the below "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" error.

Our echarts is implemented in the above plugin.  [Here](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=tree-basic) is the echarts tree widget that we're using, but it's a standalone implementation -- no grafana involved, just wanted to get you a visual of the kind of tree we're trying to render.

We've got the right json tree structure 'hard configured' on the grafana echart plugin's 'function' panel and rendering correctly -- it's a good looking tree with an animated render that shows all of our nodes.  Very nice.
...but that's just statically configured, we need smthg dynamic.  So we then created a different dashboard that used [this datasource plugin](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/marcusolsson-json-datasource/) to retrieve our known-good json tree structure from a wiremock REST API.  Ultimately, the real REST API will dynamically render various json trees based on two input parameters to the REST API.

When editing the grafana dashboard, when we toggle on the plugin/panel's "table view", it shows that we've retrieved the right json pulled from the wiremock REST API.

[image: JSON API Grafana Datasource successfully pulls our tree json from wiremock REST API]

That's the good news.
But when we toggle off "table view" (blue toggle in screenshot above) to try to show the rendered tree, all heck breaks loose and we only see the following exception with no tree :-(

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at dt (http://myhostname.com:4000/public/plugins/volkovlabs-echarts-panel/module.js?_cache=5.1.0:3:377592)
at dt (http://myhostname.com:4000/public/plugins/volkovlabs-echarts-panel/module.js?_cache=5.1.0:3:377734)
at dt (http://myhostname.com:4000/public/plugins/volkovlabs-echarts-panel/module.js?_cache=5.1.0:3:377957)
at dt (http://myhostname.com:4000/public/plugins/volkovlabs-echarts-panel/module.js?_cache=5.1.0:3:377957)
at dt (http://myhostname.com:4000/public/plugins/volkovlabs-echarts-panel/module.js?_cache=5.1.0:3:377957)
at dt (http://myhostname.com:4000/public/plugins/volkovlabs-echarts-panel/module.js?_cache=5.1.0:3:377957)
at dt (http://myhostname.com:4000/public/plugins/volkovlabs-echarts-panel/module.js?_cache=5.1.0:3:377957)
at dt (http://myhostname.com:4000/public/plugins/volkovlabs-echarts-panel/module.js?_cache=5.1.0:3:377734)
at dt (http://myhostname.com:4000/public/plugins/volkovlabs-echarts-panel/module.js?_cache=5.1.0:3:377957)
at dt (http://myhostname.com:4000/public/plugins/volkovlabs-echarts-panel/module.js?_cache=5.1.0:3:377957)
```

There is a JSONPath expression that pulls the 'right' part of the tree from the REST API response.
Because our working static example has our entire tree stuffed in the echarts 'data' attribute,
I'm using JSONPath expressions that point to, essentially, the root of the tree.
All of the following jsonpath expressions resolve to various subtrees and produce the same RangeError:

```
$
$.
$[0]
children[3]
children[3].children[0].children[0]
children[3].children[0].children[1].children[0]    #This is a leaf node!
```

Here is the URL configured in our data source: http://myhostname.com:4001/api/u-qg/

Actual URL to the REST API:
http://myhostname.com:4001/api/u-qg/tree?myqg-prj=prj-MyProduct-uqg&myqg-svc=svc-MyProduct-uqg

I've looked at other examples for this echarts plugin, [like these](https://volkovlabs.io/plugins/volkovlabs-echarts-panel/datasources/#pie-chart).  While they don't use they same JSON API Datasource that we're using, they seem to pull a resultset from the Datasource.  If these examples used JSON, perhaps it would be a json array with a handful of data points.  My point is that our implementation described above just pulls the single root node from it's datasource (the wiremock REST API).  I'm wondering whether that difference is part of the problem.

Here is the most important part -- the most likely place to cause problems I think.  This is our javascript code that is in the echarts plugin's "function" panel, as documented [here](https://volkovlabs.io/plugins/volkovlabs-echarts-panel/options/).

It is responsible for pulling our known-good tree out of the json from the datasource's REST API call and embedding in into a structure that will be passed to echarts.  Note that the stringify function (stolen from somewhere on SO) is just used for debug.

```
function stringify(obj) {
  let cache = [];
  let str = JSON.stringify(obj, function (key, value) {
    if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
      if (cache.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
        // Circular reference found, discard key
        return;
      }
      // Store value in our collection
      cache.push(value);
    }
    return value;
  });
  cache = null; // reset the cache
  return str;
}
console.log("#@a");
let jsonTree;
console.log("#@b");
data.series.map((s) => {
  console.log("#@c");
  if (s.refId === "A") {
    console.log("#@d");
    jsonTree = s.fields.find((f) => f.name === "JsonTree")
    console.log("#@e");
    console.log("Found the tree:" + stringify(jsonTree))
    console.log("#@f");
  }
});

console.log("#@g");
return {
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'item',
    triggerOn: 'mousemove'
  },
  animationDurationUpdate: 15000,
  animationEasingUpdate: 'quinticInOut',
  series: [
    {
      type: 'tree',
      data: [jsonTree],
      top: '1%',
      left: '20%',
      bottom: '12%',
      right: '20%',
      symbolSize: 5,
      edgeShape: 'polyline',
      initialTreeDepth: 5,
      lineStyle: {
        width: 1,
        color: '#664327',
      },
      label: {
        position: 'top'
      },
      leaves: {
        label: {
          position: 'right',
          verticalAlign: 'middle',
          align: 'left'
        }
      },
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'descendant'
      },
      expandAndCollapse: true,
      animationDuration: 550,
      animationDurationUpdate: 750
    }
  ]
};
```

Matthias Mertens suggested to confirm whether our tree structure has cyclic references.  It doesn't -- or please correct us if we're wrong about this.  The 'hard configured' approach used the exact same tree and did not complain.  Below is the tree we're embedding on the echarts 'options' structure -- the value of the 'data' attribute.  FYI, I copied this from the Datasource's "Table View" (a debugging shortcut), so we know the Datasource correctly retrieved this from wiremock.

```
{
    "name": "MyProduct Universal Gate",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "CapacityPlanning",
            "value": "54",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "name": "CodeQuality",
            "value": "54",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "SONAR-Qube",
                    "value": "54",
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Security",
            "value": "54",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "SIEM",
                    "value": "54",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "StaticCodeScanning",
                    "value": "54",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Checkmarx",
                            "value": "54",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "VeraCode",
                            "value": "54",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "WhiteBox-auto-pennetation-testing",
                    "value": "54",
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "SRE-Gate",
            "value": "54",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Chaos",
                    "value": "54",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Chaos-NetworkDisconnect",
                            "value": "54",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "01-PRE-NetworkDisconnect",
                                    "value": "54",
                                    "hyperlink": "https://myqghostname.com/bridge/evaluation/e4f8ba6d-cf59-4c09-862e-d334e2d65e1b/stage-acceptance-zone",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "02-FAIL-NetworkDisconnect",
                                    "value": "54",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "03-POST-NetworkDisconnect",
                                    "value": "54",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Chaos-PodDelete",
                            "value": "54",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "01-PRE-PodDelete",
                                    "value": "54",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "02-FAIL-PodDelete",
                                    "value": "54",
                                    "children": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "03-POST-PodDelete",
                                    "value": "54",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Performance",
                    "value": "54",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "baseline-workload-100",
                            "value": "54",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "baseline-workload-200",
                            "value": "54",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So that's a big ugly tree.  Might be pretty easy to miss a cyclic reference, right?  So I tried a sneak attack!!  I used this expression:

```
children[3].children[0].children[1].children[0]
```

to squash the big tree down into a single, lonely leaf:

```
[
  {
    "name": "01-PRE-PodDelete",
    "value": "54",
    "children": []
  }
]
```

...and even that pitifully small structure produces the EXACT same error.  Sad face.  :-(

I have a .har file if that would be helpful to anyone, 200k ish, so omitting it until someone asks.

Comment: the `stringify` function you are using for debugging removes circular references. Does your tree contain circular references? If so this could be causing such an error.

Comment: Thanks Matthias Mertens, I updated the post to include the whole tree.  We don't see any circular references, do you?

Comment: Hmm.. and the returned echarts option is used to initialize the chart?

Comment: Correct, I just updated the q with the doc link:  https://volkovlabs.io/plugins/volkovlabs-echarts-panel/options/

Comment: Yeah sry no idea. I dont know grafana and all the plugins but if you pass a plain json object to echarts it should usually work. So I suspect there is an issue within the plugin. What happens if you pass different data via this way? or if you pass the same data to a sunburst series?